# Как сделать не активную текущую ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

На wordpress при посещении страницы в меню всё равно можно нажать на текущую страницу и снова по ней перейти. Нужно отменить данное действие

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант.

- Найти класс у активного элемента в меню
- Применить к этому классу сss правило pointer-events: none; (Вариант
  подойдет если у вас нету выпадающих подменю)

Js вариант

- Ищите js вашу ссылку
- "Слушаете" клики по ней
- event.preventDefault()

php вариант

- В цикле который создает меню, заменяете ссылку у активного элемента на какой либо другой тег, например span

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav__link--active {
    background: #e1c374;
    pointer-events: none; 
    cursor: default;
}

$(function() {
    $('.nav__list li a').each(function() {
        var location = window.location.href; //текущая ссылка на сайте
        var link = this.href;
        if (location == link) { // если текущая ссылка равна ссылке по которой перешел-добавляем стили active
            $(this).closest("li").addClass('nav__link--active');
        }
    });
});
```